# Bluetooth headphones connect to "Forward VoIP Calls to Handsfree" but not to "Listen to Music"

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, voip

After restarting my computer, I can always connect my bluetooth headphones just fine. However, if they disconnect (intentionally or not) I open the device under "Devices and Printers" and connect again. I can always connect to "Forward VoIP Calls to Handsfree" but often not to "Listen to Music." Why would I be able to connect to one and not the other? I would rather not restart every time I wish to listen to music.

Note: Upon clicking "Listen to Music" (or "Retry" after it has failed once), it immediately reads "Connection failed" seemingly without attempting to connect. A successful connection always takes at least a moment to connect.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at https://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/128671-bluetooth-headset-pairs-but-wont-connect-not-avail-playback-devic-4.html - use **Start**->**Control Panel**->**Administrative Services**->**Services**[.lnk] OR **Task Manager**->**Services**[tab] and click on the **Services** button at the bottom right.

In the **Services** window, select the **Bluetooth Media Service** and either **Action**->**Restart** or *right-click*->**Restart**

You should now be able to connect for music!